# Keycloak return service in user api

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

Hi I use Keycloak API to get users with status enabled
`GET /auth/admin/realms/Test/users?enabled=true`

Receives users that are not on the user card in Keycloak

for example: `[ {"username": "service-account-test" ...}, {"username": "service-account-test2" ...} ]`

How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The users with the prefix `service-account-` are automatically created by Keycloak for each client that has the OAuth2 flow `client credentials` enabled, which is represented in Keycloak with the option `Service Accounts Enabled`.

Therefore, you can query for the list of clients using the [endpoint](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/12.0/rest-api/index.html#_clients_resource):

```
GET /{realm}/clients
```

filter to only get the clients with the field `"serviceAccountsEnabled"` set to `true`.

Then you can use that list to filter the users that you do not want, knowing that those users will have the name `service-account-clientID` where clientID is the clientID of the clients with the service account enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a blacklist to reduce the returned userlist. The endpoint doesn't support any negated lookup logic ([see the endpoint specification](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/12.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource)).

Example:

```
Map<String,String> users = /* from rest API - map only as example /*
String[] blacklist = {"service-account-test", "service-account-test2"};
for(String blacklistEntry : blacklist) users.remove(blacklistEntry);
```

The runtime effect on this should be negligible at best.

Comment: @dreamcrash You're totally right, my mistake. I'll edit this part out, the solution however should be unaffected by this!

Comment: And what if I do not know what services-* will be created in a different environment

Comment: But i can create user with this prefix

Comment: It really depends on how you actually handle the API's response. You could however query the clients once and then generate the blacklist in a singleton on application startup (i don't know though whether that's a legit use case for you or not!). For the username problem, you could force to use e-mails as username (if it makes sense for your application) and then just query the `users` endpoint for `email=@` and `exact=false`.

Comment: @maio290 users with @ in the name would probably solve the problem, but I don't have such users, generating a blacklist when starting the application does not solve my problem